# how to delete old lib files

Tags: 20.04, kernel, directory, libraries

is it correct/advisable to delete the old files under usr/lib/modules, if yes how to delete these directories.

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Mar  3  2022 5.4.0-100-generic

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May  2  2022 5.4.0-109-generic

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 17 11:54 5.4.0-131-generic

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 14  2021 5.4.0-42-generic

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 19  2021 5.4.0-62-generic

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb 24  2022 5.4.0-88-generic

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the old module directories do not get purged or even autoremoved.  These are probably shown from dpkg -l linux- as in
the "rc" state.  If you cannot purge the package specifically:

```
sudo apt purge 5.4.0-88-generic
```

to get rid of them, just delete them.
From the /lib/modules directory, you may just recursively remove them:

```
sudo rm -rf 5.4.0-88-generic
```

etc.